Spring Security - How do I delete a Security Context from Redis?
I have a Spring OAuth Client, that persists most things to Redis, as you can see below

How, however can I delete a security context object from Redis? Otherwise I'm assuming it will just keep building up. I can delete the sessions, I have a session evictor for that:
Redis Session Clean Up
I can also set the time limit to each session
Redis Indexed Session Repository
(see line 35)
But for Security Context, and Authorized Clients, when or how do these get deleted?
Redis Security Context
(where do I set a time limit, or how do I delete these)
Redis Authorized Client
(similarly, where do I set a time limit, or how do I delete these)
Should I add them as attributes instead, to the main session object / map?
